# Submitting files in Solr

Tags: json, xml, csv, solr, requesthandler

While I submit documents to Solr if Request-Handler is **/update** I can't submit csv and json files but I can submit xml files.

I have changed Request-Handler to **/update/extract**. Now I can submit csv,json and xml files. But the problem is when I execute the query I can see the informations about file not the things inside the file.

You can see the outputs: https://ibb.co/eoTQaF

Now, I want to submit csv, json and xml files but I want to see the content of the files too. Do you have any idea ??

Comment: shows us exactly what command are you using to submit a json to /update...

Comment: Here you can check: https://ibb.co/dTHCNv

Comment: How did you try to submit the JSON? You'll have to set the correct content-type for Solr to detect it as JSON (i.e. `application/json`. You can do this with cURL with `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **/update/extract** in **Request-Handler (qt)** instead of only **/update**. You can submit your json or csv files with this way.